# start flask server @ startup with supervisor: FATAL Exited too quickly

Tags: python, flask, supervisord

I am trying to start my flaskserver at startup with the help of supervisor. But i get this error message:

```
python_auutostart                FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

This is the entry in my logfile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/flaskserver/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

This is my .conf:

```
[program:python_auutostart]
user=nobody
command = python run.py
directory = /home/flaskserver/
autostart = true
autorestart = true
stderr_logfile=/etc/supervisor/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/etc/supervisor/long.out.log
```

I can start my flaskserver without problems if I run ./run.py but I don´t get it to run with supervisor. I don´t see why i get the ImportError i posted. Maybe some1 can point me to my probleme here.

Comment: May or you have to be in the virtualenv where the flask is installed

Comment: I moved the .conf file into my virutalenv and but i still get the same error

Comment: You need to use the python from the virtualenv. So use something like `/path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/python`

Comment: thank you @syntonym this was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python you use is the default system python (you can check that wich `which python` which should display something like `/usr/bin/python` or wherever your system python is). This does not have access (by default) to libraries that are installed in a virtual environment. Instead you should use the python that is specific to the virtualenv. You can do that by explicitly calling the python which should be located in `/path/to/virtualenv/env/bin/python`. You can check that by activating the virtualenv and `which python` which should output the path to the python of the virtualenv.